# Is there a way to type-check just a function's parameters in Typescript in the arguments of another function?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a function that takes in another function and that function's arguments. Here is an example:

```
function foo(inputFunc: (...args: any[]) => void, ...args: Parameters<typeof inputFunc>) { ... }
function bar(a: string, b: string) { ... }

foo(bar, "string A") //I want this to show an error in the IDE because argument B is missing.
```

I have tried this:

```
function foo(inputFunc: (...args: any[]) => void, ...args: Parameters<typeof inputFunc>) { ... }
```

But the type of `args` is always `any[]`, because inputFunc has the type `(...args: any[]) => void`. Is there any way to change the type of `...args` in `foo` so that it is dependent on the parameters of `inputFunc`?

**EDIT**

And of course, right after posting I figured out the answer to my own question:

```
function foo<F extends (...args: any[]) => void>(inputFunc: F, ...args: Parameters<typeof inputFunc>) { ... }

function bar(a: string, b: string) { ... }

foo(bar, "string A") //Throws an error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generics to type the passed function so that it can be used by `Parameters`:

```
function foo<T extends (...args: any) => void)>(inputFunc: T, ...args: Parameters<T>) {

}

foo(bar, "string A") // Error
foo(bar, "string A", "string A") // OK
foo(bar, "string A", "string A", "string C") // Error
```

Comment: Alright, thanks! I just figured it out myself too! Even though I was trying to figure this out for a solid 15 minutes, it's always when you got to ask someone else about it that you find the answer yourself.